# Using my own class in App to store pairs

Tags: android, arrays, class, imagebutton

I'm assigning 12 ImageButtons their own ids and then giving each one of 6 random images. I want 6 pairs of 2. I created my own class "Pairs" to store them but it crashes
I've left out some of the initializing just to avoid cluster but this is the basic setup

```
class Pairs {

int first;
int second;

public void setFirst(int a){
    first = a;
}

public void setSecond(int a){
    second = a;
}

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Boolean isShown[];
    Pairs imagePairs [] = new Pairs[6];
    gen = new Random();
    int randomAssign = 1;
    while(randomAssign < 13){
        b = gen.nextInt(12) + 1;
        while(isShown[b] == true){
            b = gen.nextInt(12) + 1;
        }

        if (randomAssign < 2){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img01);
            imagePairs[0].setFirst(b);

        }
        else if (randomAssign <3){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img01);
            imagePairs[0].setSecond(b);

        }
        else if (randomAssign < 4){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img02);
            imagePairs[1].setFirst(b);

        }
        else if (randomAssign <5){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img02);
            imagePairs[1].setSecond(b);
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 6){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img03);
            imagePairs[2].setFirst(b); 
        }
        else if (randomAssign <7){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img03);
            imagePairs[2].setSecond(b);
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 8){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img04);
            imagePairs[3].setFirst(b); 
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 9){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img04);
            imagePairs[3].setSecond(b);
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 10){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img05);
            imagePairs[4].setFirst(b); 
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 11){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img05);
            imagePairs[4].setSecond(b);
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 12){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img06);
            imagePairs[5].setFirst(b); 
        }
        else if (randomAssign < 13){
            buttons[b].setImageResource(R.drawable.img06);
            imagePairs[5].setSecond(b);
        }

        isShown[b] = true;
        randomAssign++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between

```
Pairs imagePairs [] = new Pairs[6];
```

And

```
imagePairs[0].setFirst(b);
```

You need somewhere to initialise your pair:

```
imagePairs[0] = new Pairs();
```

If you dont, imagePairs[0] will be null and you will get a NullPointerException...
Obviously, the same applies to imagePairs[1], imagePairs[2] etc.

*Edit:* This can be done with a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<imagePairs.length; i++){
    imagePairs[i] = new Pairs();
}
```